# Why does the heat equation have a Fourier series solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why when solving the heat equation why does the solution consist of of an infinite fourier series instead of some finite linear combination of cosines or sines?

I have read several tutorials on this and have not found an adequate explanantion as to why this is

Its like they make a jump to an infinite series like a magician pulling a rabbit from a hat and i'm left confused

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are solving the heat equation, say, in an interval $[0,L]$ with an initial temperature distribution
$$u(x,0)=f(x)\qquad(0\leq x\leq L)\ ,$$
where $f$ is an "arbitrary", at any rate not "cooked up" function. In such a case you cannot expect that a finite linear combination of "basis solutions" $(x,t)\mapsto U_k(x,t)$ is able to mimic for $t=0$ the exact function $f$ given in the initial condition.